# Two divs in one container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so I have a fluid container width 100% and inside of that is two fluid divs width 45%, left div will be text then second div will be either an image or more text.

CSS:

```
    #aboutContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 94%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.box {
    width:32.333%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0.5%;
    border:1px solid #999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:#efefef;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="aboutContainer">

<div class="aboutBox">
<p>
Text input
</p>
</div>

<div class="aoutBox">
<p>
Text input
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The classes don't match your CSS?

Comment: Your classes are wrong - you need .aboutBox, not .box (to work with that HTML)

Comment: If the container should be 100% width, and the children 45%, why did you set them to 94% and 32.333%?

Answer (score 1):

Your classes were named incorrectly. I corrected that and set the width percentages to what you specified in your post and it worked for me.

HTML

```
<div id="aboutContainer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Text input
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Text input or image
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#aboutContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0.5%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQRGKj

Comment: Thank you very much, however the container is not spanning the entire page.

Comment: You have a `max-width: 1000px;` so if the page is larger it wont span the entire page

Comment: You had specified the max-width in your original CSS so I assumed you wanted to keep that. I'll edit my post so it spans the entire width.

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your code. You have CSS class `.box`, but in the HTML you use `aboutBox` and `aoutBox`.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Voreny/n8wxnpdj/) with typos corrected, yet it's probably not what you want.

[Here's another JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Voreny/0e8Leg89/) that most likely is what you want. When using flexbox you do not need to provide specific widths, as flexbox will take care of that. For `justify-content` you can experiment with `center`, `space-between`, and `space-around`.

```
#aboutContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    margin:0 0.5%;
    border:1px solid #999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:#efefef;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one  missing at the bottom, also the classe's name in the html doesn't match the CSS classes' names (eg. if the css is applied to .box then your HTML should also say class="box").

The css rules needs to be changed as well.